# Repeat rows with specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to repeat rows contain specific values in R with `df` as below

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("x","y","z"),
                 name2 = c(0,1,2))
df

  name1 name2
1     x     0
2     y     1
3     z     2
```

My desired output

```
  name1 name2
1     x     0
2     x     0
3     y     1
4     y     1
5     z     2
```

I would like to say only rows containing 'x' and 'y' will be repeated one time.
So far, I only came up with the idea of using `add_row` and replace `NA` values by the corresponding values. Any sugesstions for this using `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column specifying number of times a row should be repeated and then use `uncount` to repeat them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(repeat_row = ifelse(name1 %in% c('x', 'y'), 2, 1)) %>%
  uncount(repeat_row)

#  name1 name2
#1     x     0
#2     x     0
#3     y     1
#4     y     1
#5     z     2
```

Answer (score 4):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(name1=="x" | name1=="y") %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  arrange(name1)
```

```
  name1 name2
1     x     0
2     x     0
3     y     1
4     y     1
5     z     2
```

Comment: what about if we have more rows than that. I already editted my question, bro

Comment: It works also with the new df!

Comment: my bad. The way you are doing here is to bind the row with the `df` already exist. What if the `df` here is in the pipe, then I would like to do this step within the flow.

Answer (score 3):

We may also do this as

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%  
   uncount(1 +(name1 %in% c('x', 'y')))
  name1 name2
1     x     0
2     x     0
3     y     1
4     y     1
5     z     2
```

Answer (score 2):

I just couldn't remember, but I thought there was a shorter way to do this:

```
df[sort(c(seq_len(nrow(df)), rep(which(df$name1 %in% c("x", "y")), 1))),]

    name1 name2
1       x     0
1.1     x     0
2       y     1
2.1     y     1
3       z     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `tidyr::add_row`, but describe what you want to put into the row by using indexing.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("x","y","z"),
                 name2 = c(0,1,2))
df %>% 
  add_row(df[1,], .before = 2) %>% 
  add_row(df[2,], .before = 3)
```

Comment: same my side, i also only use `add_row`